# List of all unobtrusive validation attributes for each Validation Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation, unobtrusive-javascript

I need a reference list of all unobtrusive validation attributes for each Validation Attribute. Something like:

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for here.  Do you want a list of data annotations available as Attributes in MVC, a list of jquery validation validators, or what?

Comment: I have updated the question :)

Comment: Are you asking for us to recommend an off site resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC ships with unobtrusive validators for each of the Data Annotation Validators that it provides. Taken from [Validation with Data Annotation Validators](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs), here is that list:

> **Using the Data Annotation Validator Attributes**
>
> When you use the Data Annotations Model Binder, you use validator attributes to perform validation. The System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace includes the following validator attributes:
>
> - Range – Enables you to validate whether the value of a property falls
>   between a specified range of values.
> - ReqularExpression – Enables you    to validate whether the value of a
>   property matches a specified    regular expression pattern.
> - Required – Enables you to mark a property    as required.
> - StringLength –
>   Enables you to specify a maximum length    for a string property.
> - Validation – The base class for all validator    attributes.
> - **DataType** - *Additional validations for specific data types, like phone numbers, credit cards and email addresses. Not in the referenced link.*

See also https://dataannotationsextensions.apphb.com for additional validators that can be included in your application.

*As far as client side tag attributes are concerned, these are processed by the unobtrusive adapters that the above annotations generate. These are prefixed with "data-val-". Additional parameters for the validator would be added as additional attributes. For example:
regex becomes data-val-regex="Message" data-val-regex-pattern="some pattern"*

From MVC3 `jQuery.validate.unobtrusive.js`:

```
adapters.addSingleVal("accept", "exts")
        .addSingleVal("regex", "pattern");

adapters.addBool("creditcard")
        .addBool("date")
        .addBool("digits")
        .addBool("email")
        .addBool("number")
        .addBool("url");

adapters.addMinMax("length", "minlength", "maxlength", "rangelength")
        .addMinMax("range", "min", "max", "range");

adapters.add("equalto", ["other"], function (options) {
        // removed for brevity
});
adapters.add("required", function (options) {
    // removed for brevity
});
adapters.add("remote", ["url", "type", "additionalfields"], function (options) {
    // removed for brevity
});
```

Comment: I don't think you'll find what you are looking for, and the answer for all the potential combinations is not something I have time to provide. Consider that the DataTypeAttribute provides 17 different enumeration values. Regardless, those will result in one of the adapters listed above. I would suggest adding a view model with the attributes that you need and generating a scaffold to see what it generates.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and although there is an answer there was still a lack of a simple table describing the different attributes in C# and the matching data attributes. Below is table with this information.

**Table**

[image: Data Validation Attributes Table]

**Notes**

- All data validation attributes will create a data attribute of the form `data-val-<name>="<message>"` and any attributes will be of the form `data-val-<name>-<param>="<value>"`
- In the table the *HTML Name* column represents the name in the data attribute. Eg. `data-val-maxlength`
- In the table the *Parameter Name* column represents the parameter name in the data attribute after the validation name. Eg. `data-val-maxlength-max`
- The *Message Index* column is the index of the parameter in the ErrorMessage, index 0 is always the field name. Eg. `ErrorMessage = "The field {0} cannot be longer than {1}"`
- This data is taken from the .NET Core repositories, there may be other attributes provided by other libraries

**References**

- [ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/ValidationAttributeAdapterProvider.cs)
- [Data Annotation Provider Sources](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations)